# GetItem(int) to return Listfragment in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, fragmentpageradapter

I am developing an Android app made up by 3 List fragments. I'm using a `ViewPager` object to make the user swipe between fragments. I have used the same code with fragments. But when I change it to use list fragments i'm getting an error

```
the return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)
```

I'm stuck here for hours. please help..

My Fragment Activity

```
public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

    List<ListFragment> fragments = getFragments();

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

}

private List<ListFragment> getFragments(){
    List<ListFragment> fList = new ArrayList<ListFragment>();

    fList.add(AllMsgFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
    fList.add(ErrorMsgFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
    fList.add(SuccessMsgFragment.newInstance("Fragment 3"));

    return fList;
}
```

and my FragmentPageAdapter

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<ListFragment> fragments;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<ListFragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {//The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Page #" + ( position + 1 );
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that you import the right class "import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;" do not use "import android.app.ListFragment;" or other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, thank you @hieuxit. Changing

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

Solved my issue...